# Using vscode for android developpement

Tags: java, android, gradle

I'm trying to use vscode to create an android application using gradle 7.3.3 and jdk 18.0.2.1 but I have an issue. It's my first time doing this and I don't realy get what is the problem. I got this error :

```
class.java is not on the classpath of project app, only syntax errors are reported
```

I probably forgot to do something to configure vscode.
I hope you can help me.

Thank you !

Comment: I am not familiar with VSCode but what is stopping you from using Android Studio?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! In order to answer your question it world be helpful if you provide as much information as possible. What action did you take that resulted in the output? What happens if you run grade from the command line?

Comment: Hey , @JohnnyLambada thanks for your message. I can use vscode and build my project using gradle cli with no problem. But due to this problem, Vscode is limited: it can make imports, reference others errors than syntax. To anwser to Lawrence Gimenez, I juste prefer Vscode because of it is the one i use everyday and i've configured it pour être plus efficace. Android Studio is a very good IDE but it's just a personal preference. I'll use it if I've no solution but I prefere to try my best with Vscode before X)

Comment: @LawrenceGimenez